# How to get a list of messages for a Discord thread?

Tags: python, discord.py

In 2021 Discord API added a new feature - thread. Suppose that I have a thread and I want to get a list of messages in the thread. How can I do it? The documentation says that threads are like "sub-channels", but the threads do not implement channel methods. The type of thread object is just `Message`.

Below is an example of the Python program:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in bot.get_all_channels():

        for channel in guild.text_channels:
            async for message in channel.history(limit=100):
                if message.content == "My Thread Name":
                    pass
                    # TODO get individual messages in the thread
```

Comment: Are you on the discord.py 2.0 alpha version? Because as far as i know, threads do not work with the latest stable release (1.7.3) yet.

Answer (score 1):

The alpha version has this:

```py
...
for thread in channel.threads:
    async for message in thread.history()
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.TextChannel.threads

If you are not using alpha version, you can install it like this

```sh
$ pip install git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

You may also use one of library's forks: `disnake`, `nextcord`, `pycord`

Comment: Is it possible to get threads only for specific message?

Answer (score 1):

I switched from discord.py to [Nextcord](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).
The nextcord API supports threads:

```
async for message in channel.history(limit=100):
   if message.flags.has_thread:
      async for m in message.thread.history(limit=100, oldest_first=True):
```